# Preferred approach for running one script over multiple directories in SLURM

Tags: hpc, slurm

My most typical use case is running a single script over multiple directories (usually R or Matlab). I have access to a high-performance computing environment (SLURM-based). From my research so far, it is unclear to me which of the following approaches would be preferred to make most efficient use of the CPUs/cores available. I also want to make sure I'm not unnecessarily taking up system resources so I'd like to double check which of the following two approaches is most suitable.

**Approach 1:**

1. Parallelize code within the script (MPI).
2. Wrap this in a loop that applies the script to all directories.
3. Submit this as a single MPI job as a SLURM script.

**Approach 2:**

1. Parallelize code within the script (MPI).
2. Create an MPI job array, one job per directory, each running the script on the directory.

I'm still new to this so if I've mixed up something here or you need more details to answer the question please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not explicitly use MPI inside your original R or Matlab script, I suggest you avoid using MPI at all and use [job arrays](https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html).

Assuming you have a script `myscript.R` and a set of subdirectories `data01`, `data02`, ..., `data10`, and the scripts takes the name of the directory as input parameter, you can do the following.

Create a submission script in the directory parent of the data directories:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --ntasks 1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task 1
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=2G
#SBATCH --time 1-0
#SBATCH --array=1-10

DIRS=(data*/) # Create a Bash array with all data directories

module load R
Rscript myscript.R ${DIRS[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]} # Feed the script with the data directory
                                                 # corresponding to the task ID in the array
```

This script will create a job array where each job will run the `myscript.R` with one of the data directories as argument.

Of course you will need to adapt the values of the memory and time, and investigate whether or not using more than one CPU per job is beneficial in your case. And adapt the `--array` parameter to the actual number of directories in your case.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. With a job array, would it be beneficial to set --ntasks to be higher than one so the jobs in the array run in parallel or is this not necessary? (I'm still a bit confused about using --ntasks in SLURM scripts in general)

Comment: sbatch would not accept "memory-per-cpu", it looks like the command is "mem-per-cpu". And right now, I'm getting an error saying "sbatch: unrecognized option '--array=1-10'...

Comment: You are right about `--mem-per-cpu`, I edited my answer. But unless you have a very old version of Slurm, `--array` should be recognised.

Comment: You were right. It turns out the version of SLURM was very old and did not have the job array option. If anyone else gets this error be sure to check which version of SLURM is running in your cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is quite obvious to me, assuming that getting good paralelism is usually difficult.

In the first approach, you ask SLURM for a set of resources, but if you ask for many CPUs, you will probably waste quite a lot of resources (if you ask for 32 CPU and your speedup is only 4x you are wasting 28 CPUs). So you will go with a small portion of the cluster processing one folder after the other.

In the second approach, you will ask SLURM to run a job per every folder. There will be many jobs running simultaneously and they can ask for fewer resources. Say you ask for 4 CPUs per job (and the speedup is 3X, which means you waste 1 cpu per job). Running 8 jobs simultaneously will take the same 32 CPUs of first approach, but only 8 CPUs will be wasted and 8 folders will be processed simultaneously.

At the end, the decision have to be taken after seeing which is the speedup with the different number of CPUs, but my feeling is that second approach will be generally preferred, unless you get a very good speedup, in which case, both approaches are equivalent.