# How to parallelize this for loop using slurm?

Tags: slurm

I have a large number of different bam files to process and here is my sbatch file:

```
#! /bin/bash
#
#SBATCH --job-name=test
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=2
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=4000
#SBATCH --output=output.%j.out
#SBATCH --error=output.%j.err

srun picard.sh
```

By this I meant to run using threads=2

And my `picard.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash

module load picard-tools/2.4.1-gcb01
module load java/1.8.0_45-fasrc01

picard=./picard-tools/2.4.1-gcb01/picard.jar
outdir=./bam2fastq/fastq
tmpdir=./tmp/

for bam in $(find . -type f -name \*.bam);
do
    echo "processing ${bam}"
    s=${bam##*/}
    r1=${s%.bam}_R1.fastq
    r2=${s%.bam}_R2.fastq
    echo $r1
    echo $r2
    java -Djava.io.tmpdir=${tmpdir} -Xmx8G -jar ${picard} SamToFastq \
        I=${bam} \
        FASTQ=${outdir}/${r1} \
        SECOND_END_FASTQ=${outdir}/${r2}
done
```

While this will process each bam with thread=2 but it will be one by one. How could I run this parallelized such like 6 bam files being processed simultaneously with thread=2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try to put your for loop in a function, put your input files in a array and launch job arrays. Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH --job-name=test
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=2
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=4000
#SBATCH --output=array_%A_%a.out
#SBATCH --error=array_%A_%a.err
#SBATCH --array=0-5


#Loading modules and variables
module load picard-tools/2.4.1-gcb01
module load java/1.8.0_45-fasrc01

picard=./picard-tools/2.4.1-gcb01/picard.jar
outdir=./bam2fastq/fastq
tmpdir=./tmp/

#Array of my inputs
INPUT=( $(find . -type f -name \*.bam) )

#my function
func () {
    bam=$1
    echo "processing ${bam}"
    s=${bam##*/}
    r1=${s%.bam}_R1.fastq
    r2=${s%.bam}_R2.fastq
    echo $r1
    echo $r2
    java -Djava.io.tmpdir=${tmpdir} -Xmx8G -jar ${picard} SamToFastq \
        I=${bam} \
        FASTQ=${outdir}/${r1} \
        SECOND_END_FASTQ=${outdir}/${r2}
}

#launch job arrays
func "${INPUT[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]}"
```

---

Note 1: you can also limit the number of processes running in parallel in case you get a lot more processes with:

```
#SBATCH --array=0-1000%100
```

In this example you will limit the number of simultaneously running tasks from this job array to 100.

Note 2: This question is highly related to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51676568/preferred-approach-for-running-one-script-over-multiple-directories-in-slurm)

Note 3: [Slurm doc for job arrays](https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use a slurm array, I found it easier to handle the parallelization with `srun` which would be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH --job-name=test
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=2
#SBATCH --output=output.%j.out

#Loading modules and variables
module load picard-tools/2.4.1-gcb01
module load java/1.8.0_45-fasrc01

for bam_file in $(find . -type f -name \*.bam); do
    srun --ntasks=1 --cpus-per-task=2 \
        picard.sh $bam_file &
done

wait
echo "Finished $(date)"
```

`srun` would then process the bam files with 2 cpus each. Note that in `picard.sh`, you need to replace the for loop with `bam=$1`.